# What's the simplest reliable way to encode multiple jpeg images in a single byte string?

Tags: multipartform-data, multipart, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to publish a Google Cloud Pub/Sub message with multiple jpeg images. It needs to go in the data body. Putting it as a base64-encoded string in an attribute won't work, because attribute values are limited to 1024 bytes:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#resource_limits

What's a simple and reliable pattern for doing that? It might seem possible to choose some fixed delimiter, but I want to avoid the possibility of that delimiter occurring inside an image. Is it possible something like `||||` might occur in a jpeg byte array? Another possibility might seem to encode as multi-part mime, but I haven't found any general-purpose non-http libraries to do that. I need implementations in both Java/Scala and Python. Or maybe can I just concatenate the jpeg byte arrays without any external delimiter, and split them based on header identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following approach may work, written in Scala, using only natural delimiters:

```
  def serializeJpegs(jpegs: Seq[Array[Byte]]): Array[Byte] =
    jpegs.foldLeft(Array.empty[Byte])(_ ++ _)

  def deserializeJpegs(bytes: Array[Byte]): Seq[Array[Byte]] = {
    val JpegHeader = Array(0xFF.toByte, 0xD8.toByte)
    val JpegFooter = Array(0xFF.toByte, 0xD9.toByte)
    val Delimiter = JpegFooter ++ JpegHeader

    val jpegs: mutable.Buffer[Array[Byte]] = mutable.Buffer.empty
    var (start, end) = (0, 0)
    end = bytes.indexOfSlice(Delimiter, start) + JpegFooter.length

    while (end > JpegFooter.length) {
      jpegs += bytes.slice(start, end)
      start = end
      end = bytes.indexOfSlice(Delimiter, start) + JpegFooter.length
    }

    if (start < bytes.length) {
      jpegs += bytes.drop(start)
    }

    jpegs
  }
```

I'm sure there's a more efficient and functional implementation, but that's for another day!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to store data in some kind of schema-based message using something like [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/) or [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). Both can generate code that can be used to serialize and deserialize messages in Java/Scala and Python.

For example, in protocol buffers, you could create a message in a file `image.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Images {
  bytes images = 1;
}
```

You could generate the python code for this with protoc compiler:

```
 $ protoc -I=. --python_out=. image.proto
```

In Python3, to add images, serialize the message, and send it, you would do the following:

```
import image_pb2
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(<project name>, <topic name>)

def send_images(images):
  img_msg = image_pb2.Images()
  for i in images:
    img_msg.images.append(i)

  msg_data = img_msg.SerializeToString()

  message_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=msg_data)
  print(message_future.result())
```

To receive the images and process them:

```
import image_pb2
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

def receive(message):
  images = image_pb2.Images()
  images.ParseFromString(message.data)
  for i in images.images:
    # Process the image
  message.ack()

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(<project name>, <subscription name>)
subscribe_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, receive)
print(subscribe_future.result())
```